# C# Random Number Generator -1 or 1 only?

Tags: c#, random, numbers

How would I go about using a random number generator to generate either 1 or -1 but not 0. I have so far: `xFacingDirection = randomise.Next(-1,2);` but that runs the risk of generating the number 0. How would I go about making not accept 0 or keeping trying for a number until its not 0.

Many thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What about this:

```
var result = random.Next(0, 2) * 2 - 1;
```

To explain this, `random.Next(0, 2)` can only produce a value of 0 or 1. When you multiply that by 2, it gives either 0 or 2. And simply subtract 1 to get either -1 or 1.

In general, to randomly produce one of *n* integers, evenly distributed between a minimum value of *x* and a maximum value of *y*, inclusive, you can use this formula:

```
var result = random.Next(0, n) * (y - x) / (n - 1) + x;
```

For example substituting *n*=4, *x*=10, and *y*=1 will generate randum numbers in the set { 1, 4, 7, 10 }.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) to determine which number to use.

```
int number = (random.Next(0, 2) == 1) ? 1 : -1);
```

It evaluates to

```
if (random.Next(0, 2) == 1)
    number = 1;
else
    number = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation. Similar to the above but slightly different. Figure more answers could help you out even more.

```
    public int result()
    {
        // randomly generate a number either 1 or -1
        int i;
        Random rando = new Random();
        i = rando.Next(0, 2);
        if (i == 0)
        {
            i = -1;
        }
        return i;
    }
```